# Better way to use a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to create a program that will display bar graphs with * the maximum number of * can be 40. I have everything working but had a question with the code. Is there a better way as you can see I have to go back to the original address twice using:

```
    p_bar_length = p_bar_length - size;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SPLATS = 40;

void bar_chart(double values[], int size)
{
    double largest = values[0]; //assign first element to be the largest

    //Find the largest value
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (largest < values[i]) // check to see if there is something larger
        {
            largest = values[i];
        }
    }

    // Find the number of spalts to use
    // with the precent based on the largest value
    int* p_bar_length = new (nothrow) int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *p_bar_length = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
        p_bar_length++; // Go to next memory address
    }

    // Go back to the orignal memory address
    p_bar_length = p_bar_length - size;

    // Pritnt the correct number of splats
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *p_bar_length; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        p_bar_length++;
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Go back to the orignal memory address
    p_bar_length = p_bar_length - size;

    delete[] p_bar_length;
}

int main()
{
    double values[6] = { 22, 40, 28, 26, 14, 46};
    int val_size = 6;

    bar_chart(values, val_size);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem with it? It's fast and concise. Especially with the comments. I'd keep it.

Comment: On an unrelated note - there's not much benefit in using `nothrow` if you aren't going to check if `p_bar_length` is `NULL`.

Comment: `double largest = *max_element(values, values+size);`

Comment: Oh my.  I think I may make it a rule to assign results of new to either a smart pointer or a `TYPE * const` pointer.  I've seen this before and it confuses everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than incrementing the pointer, use the array index:

```
p_bar_length[i] = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
```

or use pointer arithmetic:

```
*(p_bar_length + i) = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
```

Answer (score 8):

Since this is C++, the best way is *not* to use pointers; instead, **use a `std::vector`**.

That said, you can also always treat a pointer as an array and just access `p_bar_length[i]` for a given position `0 <= i < length` instead of incrementing the pointer.

Comment: True I should have used a vector instead I just typed that up really quickly and then remembered about vectors after I tested it and it worked. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this as C++ I would recommend using the standard library.

Your program is more C than C++, but if c is ok for you there is not much to improve.
On the other hand, using `vector` and `algorithm` you don't need to mess around with pointers. And using C++11 it removes the rough edges previously associated with templates and iterators.

A quick shot:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

const int MAX_SPLATS = 40;

template <typename C>
    void bar_chart(const C& values)
{
    if (std::distance(values.begin(), values.end())<1)
        return; // do some error handling

    auto largest = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());

    // Find the number of splats to use with the percent based on
    // the largest value
    std::vector<int> bars(values.size());
    std::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), bars.begin(),
        [=] (double d) { return (d/largest)*MAX_SPLATS; });

    // Print the correct number of splats
    std::for_each(bars.begin(), bars.end(), 
        [](int val){ std::cout << std::string(val, '*') << std::endl; });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> values = { 22, 40, 28, 26, 14, 46 };

    bar_chart(values);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice effort. I improved it (I think) -- mainly the spelling in the comments :)

Answer (score 4):

You do not need the first `for` loop if you use std::max_element from `<algorithm>`.

You do not need the second `for` loop if you calculate the bar length in the third `for` loop.

Something like this:

```
void bar_chart(double values[], int size)
{
    //Find the largest value
    double largest = *std::max_element(values, values + size);

    // Print the correct number of splats
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int p_bar_length = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
        cout << string(p_bar_length, '*') << endl;
    }
}
```

That way you don't need the `p_bar_length` array at all. It is only a simple `int`.

**Edit:** And you could even replace the inner for loop (example modified)

Answer (score 2):

Make another copy of the pointer to use within your loop. Much less error prone.

```
int* p_bar_length = new (nothrow) int[size];
int* p = p_bar_length;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *p = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
    p++; // Go to next memory address
}
```

P.S. Why are you using `nothrow`? Since you're not checking the value you get back from `new`, an exception will be much nicer than the mess you'll have when you get back a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You could treat p_bar_length as an array and just use consistent notation

```
int* p_bar_length = new (nothrow) int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    p_bar_length[i] = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about two in one?

```
int* p_bar_length = new (nothrow) int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *p_bar_length = (values[i] / largest) * MAX_SPLATS;
     for (int j = 0; j < *p_bar_length; j++) cout << "*";
     cout << endl;
     p_bar_length++; // Go to next memory address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather similar to the post from @mkaes, but goes one step further. Instead of using `std::transform` to create a vector of the proper lengths, then `std::for_each` to create a string the proper length from each of those, this creates a string directly from the input, and writes the strings directly from `std::transform`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

const int MAX_SPLATS = 40;

template <typename C>
void bar_chart(const C& values)
{
    if (std::distance(values.begin(), values.end())<1)
        return; // do some error handling

    auto largest = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());

    std::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"), 
        [=](double d) { return std::string((d/largest)*MAX_SPLATS, '*');} );
}

int main() {
    std::array<double, 6> values = {22, 40, 28, 26, 14, 46};

    bar_chart(values);

    return 0;
}
```

Since it's using C++11 anyway, I decided to also use an `std::array` since it seems to fit nicely for the job at hand.